# Comparando entre el elemento seleccionado y tipo en jquery

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando validar un campo input con Jquery, y quiero que me haga una validación personalizada cuando llegue a un campo email, dentro de una serie de campos, pero que no se aplique a los demás campos de formulario, si no cumple con la validación de la expresión regular.

Entonces esta condición no me funciona:

```
$(this)==$('[type="mail"]')
```

Gracias

```js
  var regexemail = /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;
    function validar() {
        $('input').change(function () {

            if ($(this).val().length < 2) {
                console.log('No puede estar vacío')
                $(this).css("border", "2px solid red")

            }

            if ($(this)==$('[type="mail"]') && $('[type="mail"]').val().length > 0) {

                if (!regexemail.test($('[type="mail"]').val())) {
                    $(this).css({
                        border: '2px solid red',
                        color: 'red',
                        
                    })
                    $(this).val("El formato de correo no es el correcto")
                }
                else {
                   
                    $(this).css("border", "2px solid green")
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Yo para encontrar un input uso: `$('#contenedor').find(':input').each(function (index, value) {if (value.type == "file" && value.value != "") {//es fichero}});` tal vez tambien te sirva para el campo mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para validar un campo por su `type` podrías usar la función `is()` de **JQuery** de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(function () {
  let inputs = $('input');

  inputs.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('[type="email"]')) {
      console.log($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" value="Soy email">
<input type="text" value="Soy texto">
```

**Referencia:** [Función is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/)